# Can the continuation monad transformer be given an Alternative instance with some and many?

Tags: haskell, applicative, continuation-passing, some-and-many, alternative-functor

We can define the continuation monad transformer as

```
data Cont r m a = Cont {run :: (a -> m r) -> m r}
```

We can give `Cont r m` an Alternative instance if `m` is a member of `Alternative` via

```
empty = Cont $ \f -> empty
ca <|> cb = Cont $ \f -> run ca f <|> run cb f
```

And then allow `some` and `many` to take on their default methods. My question is, can we define `some` and `many` in terms of `m`'s `some` and `many`, instead of the default definitions? The apparently obvious options

```
some ca = Cont $ \f -> some $ run ca f
many ca = Cont $ \f -> many $ run ca f
```

obviously do not work (they do not even type check). Is there some other way to use them (if we need `m` to also be a monad, that's fine)?

For reference, `some` and `many` must be the least solution to the equations:

- `some v = (:) <$> v <*> many v`
- `many v = some v <|> pure []`

Assuming that `some :: m a -> m [a]` and `many :: m a -> [a]` satisfy this law, so should `some :: Cont r m a -> Cont r m [a]` and `many :: Cont r m a -> Cont r m [a]`.

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

There exists no arrow from

```
(forall a. f a -> f [a]) ->
(forall r. ((a -> f r) -> f r)) -> (([a] -> f r) -> f r)`
```

that makes use of its argument in an interesting way.

The only place `forall a. f a -> f [a]` can be applied is to an `f r`. These are  the results of `(a -> f r) -> f r`, like in your "obvious options", and `([a] -> f r)`. This leaves a result of the type `f [r]`. The only thing that can be done with a `forall r. Alternative f => f [r]` to produce an `f r` is index the `f [r]` with some partial function `forall r. [r] -> r` from a natural number to some other no-larger natural number.

Comment: If `r` had some additional structure, however, perhaps something could be done.  For example maybe we could `fmap fold` the `f [r]`, and with suitable coherence laws that could be equivalent.

Comment: I would beg to differ. `some ca = Cont $ \fla -> run ca $ \a ->
 (some $ pure a) >>= fla` is sort of interesting. The question is whether this is a valid `some` instance.

Comment: You can't get the `[a]` out of an `f [a]` like  `some $ pure a` with only an `Alternative f` constraint. You need either `Monad f` or `Traversable f` to do anything with it.

Comment: @luqui Yes, that's why I was very explicit with the `forall r`s.

Comment: I mentioned that I was fine with `f`  being a `Monad`. This post is useful though, showing that `Monad` is in fact required to even get it to type-check.